# Hashes in `docker pull wordpress`

Tags: docker

Locally, I just ran `docker pull wordpress`:

```
$docker pull wordpress
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/wordpress
7268d8f794c4: Already exists 
a3ed95caeb02: Download complete 
38331772e700: Pull complete 
74507bbf90f9: Downloading [=========>                                         ] 13.47 MB/69.26 MB
c6734ca38ed8: Download complete 
616f76e75b9d: Download complete 
763f79680cbb: Download complete 
e70b2d142af2: Download complete 
62012af41161: Download complete 
33a120b6dfa1: Download complete 
ea474957253d: Download complete 
757eabb832b4: Downloading [=============>                                     ] 8.518 MB/31.61 MB
286426d94368: Download complete 
cde52c0a5f98: Download complete 
7c925ca09be1: Download complete 
7c4e1930593c: Downloading [============>                                      ] 1.127 MB/4.443 MB
9c4eeb87aed8: Waiting 
e13c8ae5c7d1: Waiting 
730edfa5d07f: Waiting
```

The `Using default tag: latest` is self-explanatory. But, it's not clear to me what all of those hashes, e.g. `c6734ca38ed8` and `a3ed95caeb02`, represent.

Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Those are sha256 hashes for all layers depends on Docker image.

Docker images are based on "layers", just like aufs or overlayFS.

So, when you pull something, Docker need all deps for some image which in a nutshell are just a differences between "commits".
You can inspect all deps using `docker images -a` to print all layers available. Or use something like [this](https://github.com/justone/dockviz)

[Layers](https://gist.github.com/loadaverage/4c6428f4bcd5c88a1664) for `docker pull mongo` as example.